# External entry point Error in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

In my Apex trigger I got an error:

> Error:Apex trigger Remittance caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Remittance: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject: External entry point

and here is my code:

```
public class OutstandingFieldUpdateOnLegal {

    public List<Legal__c> legalFieldUpdate(List<Remittance__c>newRemit){        
        Map<Id,String> remAccnt=new Map<Id,String>();
        for(Remittance__c remit : newRemit){
            if(remit.Status__c =='Manual Payment' && remit.Payment_Type__c =='Legal Settlement Payment')
                remAccnt.put(remit.Id,remit.Customer__c); 
        }
        List<Legal__c> legallist = new List<Legal__c>();
        if(remAccnt.size() >0)
            legallist.add([SELECT id,Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c,
                       Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c,
                       Final_Judgment_Date__c,Final_Settlement_Date__c,
                       Customer__c From Legal__c
                       WHERE Customer__c IN : remAccnt.Values()]);

        return legallist;
    }

    public void legalFieldUpdating(List<Remittance__c>newRemit){
        List<Legal__c> lgl =new List<Legal__c>();
        List<Legal__c> legaldata = legalFieldUpdate(newRemit);
        for(Remittance__c remit : newRemit){
            if(legaldata.size() > 0){
                for(Legal__c legals : legaldata){                                    
                    if(legals.Final_Judgment_Date__c!=Null && remit.Date__c!=Null &&
                       legals.Final_Judgment_Date__c > remit.Date__c){
                           legals.Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c = 
                               legals.Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c - remit.Payment_Amount__c;
                           lgl.add(legals);
                       }
                    else if(legals.Final_Settlement_Date__c !=Null && remit.Date__c !=Null && 
                            legals.Final_Settlement_Date__c > remit.Date__c){
                                legals.Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c = 
                                    legals.Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c - remit.Payment_Amount__c;
                                lgl.add(legals);
                            }
                    else if(legals.Final_Judgment_Date__c !=Null && remit.Date__c !=Null &&
                            legals.Final_Judgment_Date__c < remit.Date__c){
                                legals.Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c =
                                    legals.Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c - remit.Payment_Amount__c;
                                legals.Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c =
                                    legals.Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c - remit.Payment_Amount__c;                    
                                lgl.add(legals);
                            }
                }
            }
        }
        update lgl; 
    }
}
```

Can someone help me why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only got one query here, so that gives us a pretty good bead on where the issue lies:

```
        legallist.add([SELECT id,Outstanding_Final_Judgment_Amount__c,
                   Outstanding_Final_Settlement_Amount__c,
                   Final_Judgment_Date__c,Final_Settlement_Date__c,
                   Customer__c From Legal__c
                   WHERE Customer__c IN : remAccnt.Values()]);
```

`List<Legal__c>.add()` takes a single argument of type `Legal__c`. As a result, Salesforce is treating this query the same way it would if it were written out as a single sObject assignment:

```
Legal__c l = [SELECT .... FROM Legal__c ...];
```

so as to provide the right argument type to this method.

When the query returns 0 or more than 1 object in a single-sObject assignment, a `QueryException` results.

Fortunately, `List` also provides an `addAll()` method, which accepts a `List` of objects to add. Here, the type of that parameter would be `List<Legal__c>`, which is what a SOQL query against `Legal__c` would normally return.

Changing `add()` to `addAll()` will allow the query to complete in that "normal" List context, which doesn't throw `QueryException` when 0 or >1 result is returned. It's legal to call `addAll()` with an empty list, too.